# Taking the Laplace transform of the derivative of some function

Tags: laplace-transform, signal-processing

I need to find the Laplace transform of $\dfrac{dh(t)}{dt}$ where $h(t) = e^{-100t} \cdot  u(t)$ and $u(t)$ is the Heaviside function.

I have two ideas for solving this problem but I am unsure which is correct.

**Idea 1**: Take the derivative of $h(t)$ then take the Laplace transform of the result. So  $dh(t)/dt = e^{-100t} \cdot \delta(t) - 100*e^{-100t} \cdot u(t)$

**Idea 2**: Use the laplace pair for a derivative as follows: $s\cdot \mathcal{L}\{h(t)\} - e^{-100t} \cdot u(0).$ The problem, however, is that $u(0)$ is undefined, so I'm not sure about how I would proceed with this method.

I would really appreciate some help in computing this Laplace transform.

Comment: Note that in the situation of the one-sided Laplace transform, we always understand $h(0)$ as $h(0^+)$ which is in fact well-defined in your case (it is $1$). This does in fact mean that the step function does not contribute (because the entire right half of the line is to the right of the step), which might not be consistent with what you're really trying to do (which might, for example, involve a step located infinitesimally to the right of $t=0$).

Comment: @Ian Thanks! That really helped. I was able to get the answer using the information you provided. I have one more question here, if you are able to help with it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233920/finding-yt-in-a-causal-system-given-an-input-output-relationship