# Finding $y(t)$ in a causal system given an input-output relationship

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, signal-processing

> Find $y(t)$ in a causal system with input-output relationship
>
> $$\frac{dy(t)}{dt} + 3y(t) = x(t)$$
>
> where
>
> $$x(t) = e^{2t} \cdot u(-t).$$
>
> and $u$ is the Heaviside function.

To try and solve this problem, I first take the Laplace transform of both sides to get

$$sY(s) - y(0) + 3Y(s) = 0.$$

This can be simplified to

$$Y(s)(s + 3) - y(0) = 0,$$

which gets me $$Y(s) = \frac{y(0)}{s + 3}$$ So, I find $y(t) = e^{-3t} u(t) \cdot y(0)$. Is this correct?

I have a Laplace transform table that tells me the Laplace transform of $-e^{-\alpha t} u(-t) = \frac{1}{s + \alpha}$. Why does this not work here?

When $t < 0$, I took the Laplace transform of both sides to get

$$sY(s) - y(0) + 3Y(s) = \frac{1}{s-2}.$$

So, I find

$$Y(s)(s + 3) - y(0) = \frac{1}{s - 2},$$

from which I get

$$Y(s) = \frac{1}{(s - 2)(s + 3)} - \frac{y(0)}{s + 3}.$$

After doing partial fractions and taking the inverse laplace transform, I get

$$y(t) = \frac{1}{5} e^{2t} u(t) - \frac{1}{5} e^{-2t} u(t) - e^{-3t} u(t) \cdot y(0)$$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: Let me double check....I am using a table. I think you might be right.

Comment: My table says that the Laplace transform of $-e^{-\alpha t} \cdot u(-t)$ is equal to $\frac{1}{s + \alpha}$. How did you get $0$?

Comment: It is equal to zero for $t > 0$. Does that mean the Laplace transform is zero?

Comment: It is zero. Okay, I see now. Why does the formula $\frac{1}{s + \alpha}$ not work here? When is this formula valid? I will try to proceed now

Comment: I think I did it. Can you check my edit, please? Do I need to get rid of $y(0)$ from my answer?

Comment: It doesn't say anything, so I assume it's for both. So for $t < 0$, we have $u(-t) = 1$. I am going try that now.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it for $t < 0$. I edited my original post with my attempt. So just to get this straight, for these type of questions, my answer should be a piecewise function distinguishing the cases in which $t > 0$ and $t < 0$?

Comment: Okay. I see now. But the method of solving the problem is correct? Thanks so much

Comment: You start of with a non homogeneous differential equation, but when you first take the Laplace transform your result seem to be for a homogeneous differential equation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to solve:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{y}'\left(t\right)+3\cdot\text{y}\left(t\right)=\text{x}\left(t\right)\\
\\
\text{x}\left(t\right)=\exp\left(-2t\right)\cdot\theta\left(-t\right)
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Where $\theta\left(t\right)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Taking the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of both sides, gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{s}\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{y}\left(0\right)+3\cdot\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)\\
\\
\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)=0
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Solving for $$, gives:

$$\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{y}\left(0\right)}{\text{s}+3}\tag3$$

> Now, take the inverse Laplace transform on both sides and you're done.